# Recursivly add new files in subfolders

Tags: linux, bash, touch, exec

I want to add recursivly new file. This is folder structure "a/b/c/d/e". When i use this

```
find . -exec touch file$RANDOM {} \;
```

I want to get in folder a: file61 and b; in b: file79 and c; etc.
But it doesnt work and make only new file in a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find . -type d -exec touch {}/file$RANDOM \;`

-type d matches just directories and therefore makes sure `find` only does the `-exec` command for directories.

`{}` (the matched filename) needs to be up front since otherwise the -exec command executes the command from the directory find was run from.